# Why can't I initialize a vector member in a structure while declaring it?

Tags: c++, stl, g++

```
struct comp {
    long a;
    vector<int> b(9);
    bool c;
};
```

Errors:

```
code.cpp:67:19: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
code.cpp:67:19: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
```

What is wrong with this? Why doesn't g++ accept if I say that `b` will have 9 elements?

Comment: Are you asking why C++ standard does not allow this?

Comment: Yes, but more like is there another syntax to do this without using a constructor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because C++ doesn't work like that.

Initializers go in the *initializer list* of a constructor, e.g.

```
struct comp {
    long a;
    vector<int> b;
    bool c;

    comp() : b(9) { }
};
```

(Note that a class thus defined is no longer an aggregate.)

**Note**: C++11 adds member initializers, but only using copy-initialization syntax:

```
struct Foo {
    int a = 5;
    vector<char> b = vector<char>(8);
};
```

Compiler support for this is still incomplete.

Comment: That <sub> text is pure evil. Have pity for our eyes.

Answer (score 0):

`vector<int> b(9);` is a concrete data structure. It's looking for a type and label, not an actual data structure. `vector<int> b;` should be all you need.